# To use .jsp pages with Eclipse on Mac, Where do I have to put .java or .class files?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Disregard all other files but `RandomList.jsp` and `RanUtilities.java`.

[image]

This one is `RandomList.jsp`. `coreservlets` returns errors saying 'coreservlets cannot be resolved'. This made me try make a directory `coreservlets` in `WebContent` directory and put a .class file in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Random List (Version 1)</TITLE>
        <LINK REL=STYLESHEET
            HREF="JSP-Styles.css"
            TYPE="text/css">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>Random List (Version 1)</H1>
        <UL>
        <% 
        int numEntries = coreservlets.RanUtilities.randomInt(15);//here
        for(int i=0; i<numEntries; i++) {
            out.println("<LI>" + coreservlets.RanUtilities.randomInt(10));// and here
        }
        %>
        </UL>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Also, `RanUtilities.java` has `package coreservlets;` in the first line. There's no error on java syntax in both files.

```
package coreservlets;

public class RanUtilities {

    public static int randomInt(int range) {
        return(1 + ((int)(Math.random() * range)));}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int range = 10;
            try {
                range = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);}
            catch(Exception e) { // Array index or number format}
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            System.out.println(randomInt(range));}}}
```

This is a result when I ran `RandomList.jsp`.

[image]

I thought making a new directory with name `coreservlets` and putting the file would be okay(of course I tried putting .java file too). And I also tried the same thing into `WEB-INF` folder as well.

What directory do I have to place the .class or .java folder?

Comment: You should not need to mess about with the `.class` file.  Simply have the code in `Java Resources -> src -> package`

Answer (score 0):

Servlet file should be in src > package > class > .java

Comment: should just be a comment

Comment: @ScaryWombat okay.

Comment: @ScaryWombat but Im lack of reputation:(